# Why my "Save" button doesn't work?

Tags: java, actionlistener, savechanges

I have one of the biggest problem in my program. I've created Save button, but it saves if the .txt file is new (Then that button does "SaveAs" function). But when I open file, then type something and trying to save and it's not saving :S. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
fileSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(currentFile == null) {
            int saveResult = fileSelect.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(saveResult == fileSelect.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                saveFile(fileSelect.getSelectedFile(), field.getText());            
            } else {
                saveFile(currentFile, field.getText());
            }
        }
    }
});

public void saveFile(File file, String contents) {
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    String filePath = file.getPath();
    if(!filePath.endsWith(".txt")) {
        filePath += ".txt";
    }

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        writer.write(contents);
        writer.close();
        field.setText(contents);
        setTitle("Editex - " + filePath);
        currentFile = file;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you possibly swallowing the exception? Never do that, handle it.

Comment: Are you sure that `saveFile` executes when you try to save an existing opened file? I assume, that this if statement `if(currentFile == null)` does not let your method to be called.

Comment: What is `field`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  In this case, if the field is a `JTextComponent`, it will have a method specifically for saving the content.  Also, change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't handling when currentFile != null, which is what I am assuming is the case when you are trying to save a file that already has a Filename.

Do something like this:

```
if(currentFile == null) {
    // Handle if new file
} else {
    // Handle an existing file
}
```

Move

```
saveFile(currentFile, field.getText());
```

into the else part of the above if else.

At the moment you have it within the `if(currentFile == null)`, and this isn't the correct place as you are calling `saveFile(null, field.getText())` here.

---

Also

```
catch(Exception e) {

}
```

is bad, never swallow an exception and do nothing with it, you will never know if an exception happens or not, just nothing will happen.

Comment: Well thank you so much :). But it doesn't save my "Enters" is that good?

Comment: What do you mean by, it doesn't save your "Enters", what do you mean by "Enters"?

Comment: It's not saving my new lines made by "Enter" button

Comment: You need to parse the value of the textfield to find the newline characters and add them to your output file. There are plenty of examples of how to do this on-line.